vuetify 3 v-date-picker(type="month") not working in nuxt ("vue": "^3.3.4",)
"vuetify": "^3.5.7"
"vite-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.1",
"@mdi/font": "^7.4.47",
I want to select and retrieve data in YYYY/MM format from a date-picker.
v-date-picker(type="month") does not work
<v-locale-provider locale="ja">
  <v-date-picker
    v-model="datePickerModel"
    type="month"
    hide-header
    elevation="15"
   ></v-date-picker>
</v-locale-provider>

this is the result
I'm looking for something like this
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDatePicker/VDatePicker.tsx

Have you checked component docs? start with this...
there is no type property for this component. Use view-mode

when I use the prop view-mode="months". The date picker initially opens with the mont select mode. But as soon as I select the month it goes back to day select mode. Even if I exit the date picker using the @update:month the selected month-year combo never gets propagated into my model. It only propagates into the model once the day is selected.  Here is my snippet.
<v-date-picker v-model="date" view-mode="months"  no-title  :hide-header="true" ></v-date-picker>

@Jeevanprakash it is date picker. not month picker. if you want months picker (without day and year) - you need to write your own component. (or just use v-select)
